# Can the Lost Viking mini-game in Wings of Liberty be played with a controller?

Tags: starcraft-2

The only campaign achievements I haven't earned from Wings of Liberty are the ones earned by playing the Lost Viking mini-game. For whatever reason my NES trained hands could not play a top down shooter with the keyboard (more truthfully I was plain terrible at this particularly game).

This partial completion is for whatever reason bothering me so I want to give the mini-game another go. On this attempt rather than fight with my keyboard I'd like to use my Xbox controller. Can the Lost Viking be played with a controller?

Comment: Remember that bombs also destroy all enemy projectiles! This realization was all I needed for those achievements :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you will need controller software that allowed you to remap keyboard keys to the buttons on the controller.

You would need some software like [Switchblade](http://games.softpedia.com/get/Tools/Switchblade.shtml) or [Pinnacle Game Profiler](http://pinnaclegameprofiler.com/).

Comment: So this would work with practically any game that uses the keyboard?

Comment: Yes, some software also work with mouse

Comment: Switchblade doesn't support Windows 8 nor Windows 7.  The same company renamed their product and just recently added support for Windows 8.